# How to pass interface pointer through a function in Golang?

Tags: go, interface

I was testing golang functionalities and came across this concept where I can use a pointer of an interface as an interface itself. In the below code, how do I ensure that the value of `one` changes to `random`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func some(check interface{}) {
    check = "random"
}

func main() {
    var one *interface{}
    some(one)
    fmt.Println(one)
}
```

Specifically, I need ways in which I can pass an interface pointer to a function which accepts an interface as an argument.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

1. Accept a pointer to `interface{}` as the first parameter to `some`
2. Pass the address of `one` to `some`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func some(check *interface{}) {
    *check = "random"
}

func main() {
    var one interface{}
    some(&one)
    fmt.Println(one)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ksz6d4p2f0

If you want to keep the same signature of `some`, you will have to use the `reflect` package to set the `interface{}` pointer value:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func some(check interface{}) {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(check)
    if val.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        panic("some: check must be a pointer")
    }
    val.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf("random"))
}

func main() {
    var one interface{}
    some(&one)
    fmt.Println(one)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ocqkeLdFLu

Note: `val.Elem().Set()` will panic if the value passed is not assignable to `check`'s pointed-to type.

Comment: Can we do something without changing the argument type of the `some` function?

Comment: @re3el That is contrary to the question you asked

Comment: @re3el: Updated answer.

Comment: Instead of val.Kind() != reflect.Ptr, you can use val.CanSet()